# How to find next free id in angular list after deleting item from it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

Okay, so I have an modified List, where I can add things through an input form. This works fine. But when I delete an item from my list, my id conversion gets confused, which will be irritating later, because I want clear ids in my database after sync with server.

I set my ids like this

```
app.controller('New_Item_FormCtrl', function ($scope, $state, DataService) {

    //...some stuff my controller does before pushing.. 

    //Push the new item into choosen list
    DataService.itemLists[list.id].items.push({
        id: DataService.itemLists[list.id].items.length,
        title: $scope.new_Item.title,
        });

    // call the edit sketch view
    $state.go('app.new_item.detail');

});
```

Now I think an easy solution would be, to search for free ids before adding the item, so I tried something like this a few lines before:

```
//check available id's
for(var i = 0; i< DataService.itemLists[list.id].items.length; i++){
    console.log('ids: '+DataService.itemLists[list.id].items[i].id);
}
```

which generates an output like this in my console

```
ids: 0
ids: 1
ids: 3
ids: 4
```

so, my question is, how can i grab this gap between 1 and 3?

Comment: Your question is not understandable. If I'm not wrong in you are wanting to save data on server once. You can create a object in your controller. If you delete any row, you should this element from this new object. When you submits your data to the server, send this final object with the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a little workaround

after deleting or reorder issues in my list, I run this piece of code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
    $scope.items[i].id = i;
}
```

I know it's a bit messy, but it works for my issues...

Answer (score 2):

There could be many solutions for this issue but I would prefer to maintain a variable (array) which stores the pool of ids which can be used. And once used, remove the id from that pool.

```
var pool = [1,4,76,3,78] //Pool contains unused id.
```

You'll need to update this pool when you delete some items, when you use any id from the pool. Also if pool doesn't have any items, then you can create a new id dynamically.

I am not sure if the order and content is relevant to you. But if you can share more details, maybe someone can come up with better solution